# Cannot open a file using ifstream in C++

Tags: c++

I am new in programming and this is my second project. 
I followed the instructor's notes to write these to open a file using ifstream but there is always an error said 
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream::open(std::string&)'|

string filename, command;
    ifstream myfile;

```
cout << "Enter the file name: ";
cin >> filename;
myfile.open(filename);
while(myfile >> numloops)
{
    while(numloops != 0)
    {
```

part of the code

Comment: Are you adding the file extension too in the code?

Comment: The complete error is there, and no that is not a linking error. Nor does it have anything to do with the file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a C++03 compiler.

Only since C++11 can a `std::string` be used to provide a filename to the `std::fstream` constructor, or to `std::fstream::open()`.

Older versions of the standard require a C-style string, for historical reasons.

You can obtain one using `std::string::c_str()`, so:

```
myfile.open(filename.c_str());
```

Ideally, though, you'd use a non-ancient compiler instead.